# How to POST an xml element in python

Tags: python, xml, post, urllib2

Basically I have this xml element (xml.etree.ElementTree) and I want to POST it to a url.  Currently I'm doing something like

```
xml_string = xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring(my_element)
data = urllib.urlencode({'xml': xml_string})
response = urllib2.urlopen(url, data)
```

I'm pretty sure that works and all, but was wondering if there is some better practice or way to do it without converting it to a string first.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post XML file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16192638/post-xml-file-using-python)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If this is your own API, I would consider POSTing as `application/xml`.  The default is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which is meant for HTML form data, not a single XML document.

```
req = urllib2.Request(url=url, 
                      data=xml_string, 
                      headers={'Content-Type': 'application/xml'})
urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Comment: Note that you don't have to build the opener.  You can simply call `urllib2.urlopen(req)` -- urlopen can take Request objects as well as plain URL strings.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full example (snippet) for sending post data (xml) to an URL:

```
def execQualysAction(username,password,url,request_data):
  import urllib,urrlib2
  xml_output = None 
  try:
    base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password)).replace('\n', '')  
    headers = {'X-Requested-With' : 'urllib2','Content-Type': 'application/xml','Authorization': 'Basic %s' % base64string}
    req = urllib2.Request(url=url,data=request_data,headers=headers)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req,timeout=int(TIMEOUT))
    xml_output = response.read()
    if args.verbose>1:
      print "Result of executing action request",request_data,"is:",xml_output
  except:
    xml_output = '<RESULT></RESULT>'
    traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
    print '-'*60
```

finally:

```
return xml_output
```

Answer (score 0):

No, I think that's probably the best way to do it - it's short and simple, what more could you ask for? Obviously the XML has to be converted to a string at some point, and unless you're using an XML library with builtin support for POSTing to a URL (which `xml.etree` is not), you'll have to do it yourself.