# Post XML file using Python

Tags: python, xml

I'm new to Python and in need of some help. My aim is to send some XML with a post request to a URL, which is going to trigger a SMS being sent.

I have a small XML document that I want to post to the URL. Can I reference the XML document on my server in the python code that needs posting, or do I include the XML data to be sent in the actual python code. Can any help me out with an example?

Comment: You can `open` any file and send the data it contains as a string, if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to send XML I would recommend that you take a look at [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). It allows you to easily send data using POST requests.

You should be able to transmit the XML data directly from your Python code using requests.

```
xml = """my xml"""
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'}
requests.post('http://www.my-website.net/xml', data=xml, headers=headers)
```

You could also load the xml from a text-file and send that, if you don't want to have the xml document hard-coded.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want use an outside library, you can just `urllib2`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3106518/754254) for an example of how to do so.

To extract the XML from the file you just have to do

```
XML_STRING = open('path/to/xml_file').read()
```